# I'm trying to migrate SQL SERVER Express to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005, data-migration

I have a somewhat small database in SQL Server Express 2005 that I really need to migrate over to a MySQL install on my hosting service (Dreamhost).  After reading for a couple days, everything pointed to the MySQL Migration Toolkit, which is unfortunately EOL.  I was able to find an archive and install it on my server running Sql Server.  I set the source database, and set my Dreamhost MySQL as the destination.  For whatever reason I get tons of permission errors trying to migrate although the user I'm connecting to MySQL as full permissions (working with dreamhost on this).

Is there a better way to do this? I've heard that I should use some third party tools, (like dbtools) and then I heard NOT to use third party tools.

Like I said the database is small, with a few views, a few functions, and a few stored procs, which I can manually move over if needed.

What are my options? Thank you!

Comment: have you consider to export your database using sql?

Comment: @ascanio - it won't work. there are some data type mismatches between the two rdbms flavors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Export your SQL Server database to a downloadable package (SSIS?)
2. Install SQL Server Express locally.
3. Install MySQL locally.
4. Run the Migration Toolkit locally.
5. Dump the MySQL database
6. Upload and run the Dump file @ DreamHost (via phpMyAdmin if possible).

Comment: This worked! I got the schema and data copies over.  My question is did it copy the linked tables relationships?  I can recreate the relationships if needed but I was just curious.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

For such a small database you may spend more time trying to get a 3rd party tool to work for your situation than it would take you to just move the stuff manually. If you used standard SQL and little to nothing proprietary to SQL Server, creating the objects manually in MySQL should be easy enough... you just have to be aware of the slight syntax differences between the two platforms. Once the structures are created, generating insert statements to populate the data should also be trivial.